# How to look up request's text to debug using superagent?

Tags: javascript, superagent

I'm getting `400` code back from the server, so I need to check what's wrong with my request. How to print the request's raw text?

That's my code right now:

```
request.post('/api/events/')
.send(preparedEvent)
.end((err, res) => {
    if(!err){
        let returnedEvent = fromIsoToMoment(res.body);
        state = [...state, returnedEvent];
    }
    else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
return state;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** From the [source](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/client.js#L867): 
Superagent, in the send method, exposes the serialized data as `this._data`

```
 let req = request
   .post('/api/pet')
   .send({ name: 'Manny', species: 'cat' })

  req.end(function(err, res){
     if (res.ok) {
       console.log('yay got ' + JSON.stringify(res.body));
     } else {
       console.log('Oh no! error ', req._data); // Logs the data sent in request.
     }
   });
```

Comment: `res.text` would be the raw text of the response, not the request.

Comment: Please check the Update.

Comment: geat, but what should I do with this information? ;)

Comment: You wanted to print the request data. So you can just console.log the data.

Comment: i don't know javascript well, can you give me an example?

Comment: oh, so it's that simple :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems superagent supports [promise](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#request-basics) now.